# Dynamically validate the input payload on basis of a key

Tags: spring, bean-validation

I have my Pojo

```
public class AbcXyz {
    @NotEmpty
    String test_01;
    @NotEmpty
    String test_02;
    @NotEmpty
    String test_03;
    String test_req;
    @NotEmpty
    String test_04;
    @NotEmpty
    String test_05;
}
```

In my controller I am using `@Valid` to validate.
I have a countryCode which can be any country like `SG` in headers, I want to make `test_req` optional for some countries and required for some countries, How can I acheiev this dynamically on basis of countryCode?

thank you.

Is there any way or any custom annotation I can create.

Comment: You can start from here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator